# Актуальность отображения синонимов меток в общем списке

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, метки, синонимы-меток

При просмотре [списка меток сайта по имени](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=name) в первую очередь отображаются англоязычные метки, которые, видимо, прилетели к нам от enSO.

[image: метки по имени]

Для большинства из них созданы русскоязычные синонимы. Причем так, что русская метка на ruSO является основной. В связи с этим хотелось бы определиться:

1. Нужны ли синонимы меток в общем списке меток вообще?
2. Если они всё же нужны, не стоит ли отображать в первую очередь основные метки и только потом синонимы?

Если я правильно понимаю, убрать полностью англоязычные метки, которые выбраны синонимами, не получится, т.к. это создаст неудобства для разработчиков SE.

В вопросе речь идёт о Мета сайте, но основной сайт это тоже затрагивает в некоторой степени.